# JavaFX resizing window

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a problem with resizing window in javafx. I want maxHeight of stage to be at most three fourth of width of the stage. That code reproduces my issue

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        stage.show();
        stage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            stage.setMaxHeight(newVal.doubleValue() * 0.75);
            System.out.println(stage.getMaxHeight());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Problem occurs when I try to stretch window (by clicking the CORNER and dragging to resize). Width is getting bigger but at the same time I can't stretch it vertically, until I release mouse button, although value of maxHeight is much bigger than it's showed on screen (e.g. value of maxHeight is 500 but I can resize it to e.g. only 300). It looks like something is blocked until I release mouse button. I'd like to be able to resize window (by dragging the corner) vertically and horizontally simultaneously, what is not possible. I tried a lot of things (with binding) but problem remains the same.

Comment: Create and post a [mre] please.

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Read the link I posted.

Comment: Specifically: “Your code examples should be … complete. Provide all code needed to reproduce the issue in the question itself.”

Comment: Ok I pasted code, which reproduces my issue and it's as simple as possible. It's alright now? That's my first post, so sorry for my lack of knowledge about rules.

Comment: I don't think what you attempting to do will be possible (I could be wrong).  Thanks for supplying the minimal example, I voted to reopen this question, in case somebody can work out an answer.

Comment: This is a minor thing, but I suggest that you edit the the title of the question to be an actual question and to make it specific about what you are trying to do, while trying to keep it concise.  I don't quite understand why people don't ask questions when they ask questions, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I only see here the behavior I expect to see. The max height is 75% of the width, and the window resizes to the height it's dragged to, or to the max height, whichever is smaller. Both the width and height, within those constraints, change as the corner of the window is dragged. Maybe I am misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: What  version of JavaFX are you using?  Your example works for me with JavaFX 17.

Comment: I work with JavaFX 16, I think it's not version problem. I recorded video, which will exactly explain what I'm talking about https://vimeo.com/646764249

Comment: In the 17 second and further I'm not able to ,,stretch'' the window vertically, although maxHeight was increased.

Comment: can reproduce the behaviour in current fx dev (18ea). Looks like some collaborator doesn't update the max while resizing. Could be the native peer (that's the one handling the mouse interactions), don't know though. Please consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Is there any simple way to achieve similar effect I want to have?

Comment: don't know - don't even know if the behavior is a bug or a feature ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you. My last question is if can I somehow unset maxHeight? `stage.setMaxHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE)` throws an exception.

Comment: @Kacper the question about unsetting max height is actually a new question, so you could ask it as one.  My guess is that you probably can't, but you could probably just set it to a large number (e.g. 100_000), which would be effectively the same as unsetting it.

Comment: One other issue that I noted when I was trying to test this is that the problem isn't only that the height size can get "stuck" at the wrong value when resizing.  There appears to be an additional issue related to the snapping to screen borders functionality in windows, in that sometimes the height can end up larger than the set max height when you drag the window resizer close to or over the bottom of the screen because it snaps window size to the bottom border in that case, regardless sometimes of the set max size.

Comment: Thanks for help @kleopatra. Maybe in the future someone will repair that bug.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows, Linux, or macOS?  I tried with JDK 17 on macOS and it seemed to be working as intended.

Comment: only bugs that are reported have any chance of being fixed in future - did you report this?

Comment: @swpalmer my tests were on Windows and the behavior was similar to that described by Kacper (i.e. not really working as intended in some cases).

Comment: @kleopatra I haven't reported that yet, but I'll do it soon.